# SilverStripe 3 - next sibling using grandparent

Tags: silverstripe

I have a site where I want to be able to link to the next `ProductPage` from the `ProductPage` I am currently on. I can do this for immediate siblings, but once I get to the end of that set I want to link to the next `ProductRange` first product.  The structure is like this:

```
ProductArea
    ProductCategory
      - ProductRange
          - ProductPage
          - ProductPage
      - ProductRange
          - ProductPage
          - ProductPage
    ProductCategory
      - ProductRange
          - ProductPage
          - ProductPage
      - ProductRange
          - ProductPage
          - ProductPage
```

So if there is no direct sibling I need to return the next product page in order.

I'm using this for direct siblings:

```
function NextProduct() {
    $pages = ProductPage::get()->filter(array(
        'ParentID' => $this->ParentID,
        'Sort:GreaterThan' => $this->Sort
    ))->Sort('Sort'); 

    if ($pages) {
        return $pages->First();
    }
}
```

How do I get it working at the next level up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. First we try to find the next sibling. If the next sibling does not exist we get the next parent page and get their first child.

```
function NextProduct() {
    $pages = ProductPage::get()->filter(array(
        'ParentID' => $this->ParentID,
        'Sort:GreaterThan' => $this->Sort
    ))->Sort('Sort')->limit(1);

    if ($pages->count()) {
        return $pages->First();
    }

    $parent = $this->parent();
    $parentSiblings = ProductRange::get()->filter(array(
        'ParentID' => $parent->ParentID,
        'Sort:GreaterThan' => $parent->Sort
    ))->Sort('Sort');

    foreach ($parentSiblings as $parentSibling) {
        $pages = ProductPage::get()->filter(array(
            'ParentID' => $parentSibling->ID
        ))->Sort('Sort')->limit(1);

        if ($pages->count()) {
            return $pages->First();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is a `PreviousProduct` function:

```
function PreviousProduct() {
    $pages = ProductPage::get()->filter(array(
        'ParentID' => $this->ParentID,
        'Sort:LessThan' => $this->Sort
    ))->Sort('Sort')->reverse()->limit(1);

    if ($pages->count()) {
        return $pages->First();
    }

    $parent = $this->parent();
    $parentSiblings = ProductRange::get()->filter(array(
        'ParentID' => $parent->ParentID,
        'Sort:LessThan' => $parent->Sort
    ))->Sort('Sort')->reverse();

    foreach ($parentSiblings as $parentSibling) {
        $pages = ProductPage::get()->filter(array(
            'ParentID' => $parentSibling->ID
        ))->Sort('Sort')->reverse()->limit(1);

        if ($pages->count()) {
            return $pages->First();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```